# Admin user cannot access ONE folder in a samba share

Tags: 20.04, permissions, samba, windows-10, file-sharing

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2, an up until today my samba file server was running great. Today However I cant access my main folder. (I am connecting through a windows 10 PC) It says:

```
Windows cannot access \\192.168.0.43\admin
You do not have permission... Contact an admin
```

Just one folder, I can access all the rest. Here is a list of things I have tried:

- Creation a new user, with full permissions
- sudo chown -R admin /samba
- Restarting the samba service
- Restarting the server
- Trying a different PC
- Making a new user for just that folder (still cant access that folder)

I have never had this issue before, and it is just one folder, I was using it yesterday, and merely edited some text documents.

I cant figure out what is wrong for the life of me, I welcome any suggestions.
Thanks!

EDIT:
[Now I cant access the samba share at all and I get this error I have never seen before. No other devices are connected to, and I have restarted the smdb service... again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmtQ0.png)

EDIT2: Now the error above is gone, I can see my folders again, but I still cant access the one, and I get that need permission error that I posted originally. (and I did nothing) This is ridiculous. Why today....

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like more of a Windows problem than an Ubuntu one. However, when I've seen this issue crop up at the day job, the simplest solution has been to restart the `workstation` service on Windows:

```
C:\> net stop workstation /y
C:\> net start workstation
```

The `/y` forces a shutdown of the service. When `workstation` restarts, its cache files are cleared out and shares are magically accessible again.

**Note:**

If you have this issue with one of the newer Windows Server versions, you'll need to restart `netlogon` after running the above commands, as killing `workstation` shuts down `netlogon`:

```
net start netlogon
```

Comment: Unfortunately your solution did not work, thanks though. I don't think it is an issue with the windows 10 PC, because I tried another PC and I had the same issue, and I can still access all my other folders, its just one that's not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it, but im not 100% sure what fixed it. I did three different things listed bellow. If you know what probably fixed it please let me know in a comment, just in case I ever have this happen again, and I don't end up wasting another 3 hours...

firstly I changed:

```
force create mode = 0660
force directory mode = 2770
```

to this (in the samba config):

```
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
```

I added (in the samba config)(I dont think this did it cause I could edit other files before, just one folder)

```
writable = yes
```

And lastly I ran this command:

```
chmod -R 777 /path/to/share
```

This might be obvious to some people, but im pretty new to samba, and ubuntu for that matter. Anyway, hope this helps someone!